# meteor is $inc throws error, but query should be correct

Tags: meteor

I want to `upsert` an object in a meteor collection:

```
UserFollowers.upsert({user_id:user_id,size:{'$lt':10}},{
    $inc:{size:1}
});
```

But this throws an error:

***Exception while invoking method 'user_follow' MinimongoError: Cannot apply $inc modifier to non-number***

I have only one object in this collection and this query is working:

```
UserFollowers.upsert({user_id:user_id},{
    $inc:{size:1}
});
```

The query **never** no matter what the `size` is set to.

Also this query returns the object correctly:

```
UserFollowers.find({user_id:"a",size:{'$lt':10}}).fetch()
```

Do you have any ideas/suggestions?

Thx!

Comment: Is this issue still persists? Any of answers helped you to solve it?

Comment: Both answers work, but I can't find the 'requires $set' in any documentation.

Comment: Nils, you're right any of [those modifiers](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/) are valid. But somewhy Meteor work in this way, where is `$set` should be the first one. The issue still persist in latest v1.2.0.1 ?

Comment: We haven't upgraded to 1.2, yet, but I guess with the 'setOnInsert' everything should be fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Meteor seems to try to set `{'$lt':10}` as the initial value for `size` and then increase that.

What fixes the problem is this query:

```
UserFollowers.upsert({user_id:user_id,size:{$lt:10}},{
        $setOnInsert:{size:0},
        $inc:{size:1}
    });
}
```